# Disable Ctrl+Enter sublime keymap in jupyter notebook

Tags: windows, sublimetext, key-bindings, codemirror, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with the Sublime Text keymap, by adding the following to my Jupyter custom.js:

```
require(["codemirror/keymap/sublime", "notebook/js/cell"], 
function(sublime_keymap, cell) {
    cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'sublime';
});
```

...which works great mostly, except that I'm on a Windows machine and this adds the Sublime functionality of "insertLineAfter" to the binding for Ctrl+Enter, which I don't want because Ctrl+Enter is the binding to execute the current cell in Jupyter.

Does anyone know how to disable just the "insertLineAfter" binding for Ctrl+Enter please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual Sublime Text key bindings can be disabled using the `unbound` command in your `Default (OS).sublime-keymap` file. i.e. `Menu --> Preferences --> Key Bindings - User`. In your case simply add the following line.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "unbound" },
```

Since the `Add Line.sublime-macro` is quite useful you may wish to give it another binding, for example you could use `alt+enter` or `super+enter` in which case you would add the following.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "unbound" },

{ "keys": ["alt+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": 
    {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line.sublime-macro"} },
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP question.

Comment: @Tobia Yes it is and was accepted as such by the poster 4 years ago. The question asks how to unbind the `"InsertLineAfter"` binding from `Ctrl+Enter` in Sublime Text on the Windows OS. I stated how to do that and suggested how to bind that functionality to different keys since that particular line insert is useful. I suggest you re-read the question and my answer to it.

Comment: No, the question is about "sublime keymap in jupyter notebook" which has nothing to do with Sublime Text

Answer (score 9):

Following worked for me:

```
require(["codemirror/keymap/sublime", "notebook/js/cell", "base/js/namespace"],
    function(sublime_keymap, cell, IPython) {
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.keyMap = 'sublime';
        cell.Cell.options_default.cm_config.extraKeys["Ctrl-Enter"] = function(cm) {}
        var cells = IPython.notebook.get_cells();
        for(var cl=0; cl< cells.length ; cl++){
            cells[cl].code_mirror.setOption('keyMap', 'sublime');
            cells[cl].code_mirror.setOption("extraKeys", {
                "Ctrl-Enter": function(cm) {}
            });
        }
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can prevent the ctrl+enter produce a new line in jupyter notebook by comment out the following line:

```
cmds[map[ctrl + "Enter"] = "insertLineAfter"] = function(cm) { insertLine(cm, false); };
```

in the file:

```
[python lib path]/dist-packages/notebook/static/components/codemirror/keymap/sublime.js
```